# No output after new arrays being initialized in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, g++, flush

I am trying to initialise two 2D arrays, namely `psi_0` and `omega_0`, with the data type as `double`. The sizes of the arrays are `401x401`. I have written the last printing statement to check if the code is running properly or not. As soon as I initialise arrays, the last line doesn't get printed and this is getting displayed only: `PS C:\Users\Avii\Desktop> cd "c:\Users\Avii\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { g++ trialc++.cpp -o trialc++ } ; if ($?) { .\trialc++ }`.

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

void display(vector<double> &v){
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){

    const int N = 401;
    const double pi = 3.141592653589793;
    double L = pi/2;
    double r = 1.5;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
.
..
...
    double psi_0[N][N]; 
    double omega_0[N][N];
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            psi_0[i][j] = sin(x_vec[i]) * (sin(y_vec[j]));
            omega_0[i][j]= 2 * sin(x_vec[i]) * sin(y_vec[j]);
        }
        
    }
    
    cout<< "everything is fine"; // to check if the code has run till last or not!
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here `x_vec` and `y_vec` are two vectors of size `401` and data type as `double`. I have tried using `flush` but could not see the problem is solved!
Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: If you want debugging help, then please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And catch crashes in a debugger so you can tell us where in your code it happens.

Comment: You may have a stack overflow since you are creating large arrays on the stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nothing is getting printed. Only `PS C:\Users\Avii\Desktop> cd "c:\Users\Avii\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { g++ trialc++.cpp -o trialc++ } ; if ($?) { .\trialc++ }` What do you want in example to see?

Comment: The most common implementation for local variables is on the process stack. The stack is a limited resource, on Linux the default stack is 8MiB and on Windows the default size is only a single MiB. Your two arrays `psi_0` and `omeag_0` together will be almost 2.5 MiB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how can we solve this??

Comment: @drescherjm How can we solve this??

Comment: Move `double psi_0[N][N];  double omega_0[N][N];` before main or use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead?

Comment: I would recommend running your program in a debugger. then you should get more information on where the program actually crashes, and why. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173), and maybe [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: VSCode should have a debugger. I think it will show you an exit code as well so that would have told you the problem after you decoded the value by copying it to this website: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/)